# Hibernate: ManyToMany inverse Delete

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two tables, *User* and *Keyword*. The User is the owner of the relationship. If I delete a *User*, I remove first all *Keywords* from this *User* and then delete the *User*. This works as expected.

But I don't know how to delete a *Keyword* and automatically delete the relations to all *Users*.

Here is my code so far.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    
    public class User {
    
      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      @GeneratedValue
      private Integer id;
    
      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;
    
      @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
      @JoinTable(name = "user_has_keyword", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyword_id"))
      private List<Keyword> keywords = new ArrayList<Keyword>();
    
      // Getters and setters
      ...
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "keyword")
    public class Keyword {
    
      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      @GeneratedValue
      private Integer id;
    
      @Column(name = "keyword")
      private String keyword;
    
      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "keywords")
      private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    
      // Getters and setters
      ...
    }
```

```java
    @Service("myService")
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public class MyService {
    
      @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User");
    
        return query.list();
      }
    
      public User getUser(Integer id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (User) session.get(User.class, id);
      }
    
      public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
      }
    
      public void deleteUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
        // 1st, delete relations
        user.getKeywords().clear();
        session.update(user);
    
        // 2nd, delete User object
        session.delete(user);
      }
    
      public Keyword getKeyword(Integer id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (Keyword) session.get(Keyword.class, id);
      }
    
      public Keyword addKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(keyword);
    
        return keyword;
      }
    
      public void deleteKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
        // 1st, delete relations
        keyword.getUsers().clear();
        session.update(keyword);
    
        // 2nd, delete User object
        keyword = getKeyword(keyword.getId());
        session.delete(keyword);
      }
    }
```

```java
    @Controller
    public class MyController {
    
      @Resource(name = "myService")
      private MyService myService;
    
      @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String add(Model model) {
    
        Keyword k = new Keyword();
        k.setKeyword("yellow");
        k = myService.addKeyword(k);
    
        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setName("Bart");
        u1.getKeywords().add(k);
        myService.addUser(u1);
    
        User u2 = new User();
        u2.setName("Lisa");
        u2.getKeywords().add(k);
        myService.addUser(u2);
    
        return "/";
      }
    
      @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String deleteUser(Model model) {
    
        User u = myService.getUser(1);
        myService.deleteUser(u);
    
        return "/";
      }
    
      @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/keyword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String deleteKeyword(Model model) {
    
        Keyword k = myService.getKeyword(1);
        myService.deleteKeyword(k);
    
        return "/";
      }
    
    }
```

If I browse to */delete/keyword* I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.blabla.prototype.Keyword.users, no session or session was closed

I've googled and tried many different things, but nothing works.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you very much,

Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LazyInitializationException has nothing to do with deletion. You're loading a Keyword in your controller. This makes the service load the keyword, without initializing its lazy list of users. This keyword is then returned to the controller, and the transaction is committed, and the session is closed, making the keyword detached from the session.

Then you pass this detached keyword to the service to delete it. The service thus receives a detached keyword, and tries to access its list of users. Since the keyword is detached and the list of users hasn't been loaded yet, this causes a LazyInitializationException.

The service method should take the ID of the keyword to delete as argument, load it, and thus work with an attached keyword, and then proceed with the deletion.

Now to answer your question, you got it right for the user deletion: you remove all the keywords from the user to delete, because the user is the owner of the association. Apply the same logic when deleting a keyword : remove the keyword from all the users referencing it, and delete the keyword:

```
public void deleteKeyword(Integer id) {
    Keyword keyword = getKeyword(id);
    for (User user : keyword.getUsers()) {
        user.removeKeyword(keyword);
    }
    session.delete(keyword);
}
```

Note that you don't have to call update() when working with attached entities. The state of attached entities is automatically and transparently saved to the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and your help! Within the removeKeyword method I then need to check, if the User holds the Keyword: this.keywords.contains(keyword). For this contains-check I need to overwrite the equals method?! If I have thousands of User, is the contains method not too slow? I guess there is a more elegant solution. ;)

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't think, your solution is not elegant, just what I'm thinking I have to do with the "contains" method seems to be not elegant. I guess, you know a better solution than my "contains" approach. ;)

Comment: No, you don't have to override the equals method. And you don't have to check if the list contains the keyword either: you *know* it contains it. Just remove it from the list. My tests with Hibernate show that removing a user (owner side) will automatically remove the association with all its keywords, but that removing a keyword (inverse side) won't automatically remove the association with all its users. I'm not even sure that's standard behavior. The alternative is to use a native query that removes from the join table.

Comment: Ok. Yes, that's true, I don't have to check it. Thank you very much for your help and the detailed information!